# How to Check Multi radio Groups if there is one Left Unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, radio-button

[image]

I want to check if `salad` or `side dish` left unchecked after submitting.

I have a working approach but it's very ugly and I believe there is much simpler solution for such a simple task

my approach:

```
function radiosChecker(){
let radioGroups = [];
let radios = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name^="${foodId}_"][type="radio"]`); // Get all radios first

for(let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){ // Creating an array of elements each one of them representing its group
    if(i == 0){
        radioGroups.push(radios[i]);
        continue;
    }
    if(i > 0){
        if(radios[i].name != radios[i-1].name){
            radioGroups.push(radios[i])
        }
    }
}
let okays = [];
radioGroups.forEach((ele)=>{
    let group = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${ele.name}"]`); // Get all radios with same name
    for(let i = 0;i < group.length; i++){ // loop untill u find one checked and append a flag to the okays 
        if(group[i].checked){
            okays.push(true);
            break;
        }
    }
})
if(radioGroups.length == okays.length){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using `:checked` selector in `querySelectorAll()` then test if length is two

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const checked = document.querySelectorAll('.salad-radio:checked, .side-radio:checked'),
    isValid = checked.length === 2;
  console.log('Is valid: ', isValid);
})
```

```html
<button>
Validate radios
</button>


<div>
  <h3>Salad</h3>
  One<input type="radio" class="salad-radio" value="1" name="salad-type"> 
  Two<input type="radio" class="salad-radio" value="2" name="salad-type"> 
  Three<input type="radio" class="salad-radio" value="3" name="salad-type">
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Side</h3>
  One<input type="radio" class="side-radio" value="1" name="side-type"> 
  Two<input type="radio" class="side-radio" value="2" name="side-type"> 
  Three<input type="radio" class="side-radio" value="3" name="side-type">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got rid of half of the code https://gist.github.com/Z3yko/bc3fc61ca701305e9558fdb2a4069f9c

Comment: Not sure why you are pushing to the array still. Seems over complicated

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many radio groups there will be

Comment: Ahhhh ...that wasn't evident in the question. One idea also is wrap them in a container with class something like "radio-group`. Then count those elements

Comment: wow thank you that's really straight forward!

Answer (score 1):

Radio input is typically set by the `name` attribute.  Here I show how to process groups of radios by the `name` and alert those without a selected value.

- Specifically get all the radios (and the unique names)
- Process by name, choosing those that are checked
- tell me if it is not checked by comparison of the length (if it is not 1, then it is not selected) using the truthy/falsey nature of that length. (same as `checkRadios.length < 1`
- You add more groups of radios, the code does not change
- You do not have to know ahead of time how many groups of radios you have

```js
let allRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name][type="radio"]');
let names = [];
allRadios.forEach(function(element, index, allRadios) {
  names.push(element.name);
});
let uniqueNames = [...new Set(names)];

function checkMeOut(event) {
  let tellme = "";
  uniqueNames.forEach(name => {
    let checkRadios = document
      .querySelectorAll('input[name="' + name + '"][type="radio"]:checked');
    if (!checkRadios.length) {
      tellme += "Not selected " + name + '\r\n';
    }
  });
  if (tellme.length > 0) {
    alert(tellme);
  }
}

let checkem = document.getElementById('check-em');
checkem.addEventListener('click', checkMeOut);
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>My Salad</h4>
  <label>Garden</label>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="salad-type">
  <label>Slaw</label>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="salad-type"> 
  <label>Cobb</label>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="salad-type">
</div>
<div>
  <h4>My Side</h4>
  <label>Fries</label>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="side-type">
  <label>Drink</label>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="side-type">
  <label>Orange</label>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="side-type">
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Drink</h4>
  <label>Water</label>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="drink-type">
  <label>Coke</label>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="drink-type">
  <label>Beer</label>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="drink-type">
</div>
<button type="button" id="check-em">Radio - Check All</button>
```

Comment: wow I like how you checked by the validity of defining `checkRadios`  Thank you.